# Versioned txes and LUTs on localnet

Tags: versionedtransactions, lookup-tables

Attempting to build a LUT fails with `33 is not a recent slot` when running on localnet:

```
        const slot = await provider.connection.getSlot();
        const [createLookupIx, lookupTableKey] =
          AddressLookupTableProgram.createLookupTable({
            authority: wallet.publicKey,
            payer: wallet.publicKey,
            recentSlot: slot,
          });
        await provider.sendAndConfirm(
          new Transaction().add(createLookupIx)
        );
```

Looking at the recent blocks with `const slots = await conn.getBlocks(slot - 10);` shows that all of them are valid (23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33), so what's up?

Solana tools version 1.16.8, web3.js version 1.87.5

Comment: `recentSlot: slot-1` works, which is odd!

Comment: Depending on how your `connection` is configured, `getSlot` might be getting a current bank that hasn't been replayed just yet. Stick with something slightly in the past -- your solution is perfect!